# Using FFMpeg to save an rtsp stream from a certain point in time

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use FFMpeg to save a live stream **from a certain offset.** For example, "from timestamp 00:05 to 00:12".

I know how to dump the stream to file (ffmpeg -i rtsp://SRC -r 15 C:/file.mp4), the catch is how to clip it to the givem timestamp, if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try -ss and -t options? I am not 100% sure they work with streaming rtsp. But no harm trying it out. -ss is for offset and -t is for duration.